# How does Running Object Table implement weak references?

Tags: winapi, com, win32com, running-object-table

When you register a COM object in the Running Object Table with a zero flag (requesting a weak ref), the ROT increments the ref count by 1. The act of getting an object from the ROT increases the ref count by one more. Once that one is freed, the object stays alive with a ref count of at least one. Its registration in the ROT isn't magically revoked upon retrieval, either.

**How is that weak? How is that different from strong registration?**

Strong registration follows the same pattern - both registering and retrieval increments the ref count by one.

The interface pointer that the ROT returns to in-apartment clients is not a proxy; the ROT has no way of knowing that I've freed my retrieved interface pointer.

Comment: From [IRunningObjectTable::Register](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680747.aspx): *"For a weak registration (ROTFLAGS_REGISTRATIONKEEPSALIVE not set), the ROT will release the object whenever the last strong reference to the object is released. For a strong registration (ROTFLAGS_REGISTRATIONKEEPSALIVE set), the ROT prevents the object from being destroyed until the object's registration is explicitly revoked."*

Comment: I've read that. Can you please explain what does "last strong reference to the object is released" mean? If you just get the it from the ROT and then release, it doesn't free the object. In the weak scenario, the ROT holds a reference just like in the strong one.

Comment: The way I understand it (and I have to admit I never did additional checking) is that request of strong registration `ROTFLAGS_REGISTRATIONKEEPSALIVE` makes it sure that ROT holds a valid reference no matter what. Without the flag, it starts a similar way (there is simply no other way, esp. that documentation states that initial `AddRef` always happen), but the API retains the right to release the entry at any time, esp. on specific event such as release of a proxy.

Comment: A weak reference is a one-time-use scenario.  The client app does whatever it needs to do to get the server started and retrieves the object reference.  Once it is done, its last Release() call automatically also removes it from the ROT, no more references left.  The server knows it can stop running.  OLE is pretty dead so no real idea how practical this still is.

Comment: in this context 'weak reference' == 'external reference' - reference count for object from another com apartment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

really removal from ROT behavior dependent not only from `ROTFLAGS_REGISTRATIONKEEPSALIVE` flag but also are (and how) your object implemented [`IExternalConnection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680082(v=vs.85).aspx)

( *special note for @IInspectable only - yes all this is undocumented, unsupported, can changed - so please not read more* ).

when we register object in ROT com always query him for [`IExternalConnection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680082(v=vs.85).aspx) interface. if object not implemented it - used default implementation.

**in case** `ROTFLAGS_REGISTRATIONKEEPSALIVE` already at registration time [`IExternalConnection::AddConnection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686627(v=vs.85).aspx) called. so we already have 1 external connection. without `ROTFLAGS_REGISTRATIONKEEPSALIVE` - this method not called.

every time when somebody call [`IRunningObjectTable::GetObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683841(v=vs.85).aspx) (*! from another apartment*)  the `CRemoteUnknown::RemAddRef` called in our process. this method call [`IExternalConnection::AddConnection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686627(v=vs.85).aspx) **only if** we register **without** `ROTFLAGS_REGISTRATIONKEEPSALIVE` flag .

every time when we final [`Release`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682317(v=vs.85).aspx) object (*!on proxy, obtained from previous `GetObject` call* ) - `CRemoteUnknown::RemReleaseWorker` called in our local process. and it internally call  [`IExternalConnection::ReleaseConnection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687252(v=vs.85).aspx) **only** in case **no** `ROTFLAGS_REGISTRATIONKEEPSALIVE` on object. default implementation of [`IExternalConnection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680082(v=vs.85).aspx) called `CStdMarshal::Disconnect` -> `InternalIrotRevoke` when external reference (not tottal object reference) reach 0 and `fLastReleaseCloses == TRUE` - as result our object is revoked from ROT. but if we implemet [`IExternalConnection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680082(v=vs.85).aspx) by self we can call or not call [`CoDisconnectObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680756(v=vs.85).aspx) so we can be revoked or not from ROT.

and finally when we direct or indirect call [`IRunningObjectTable::Revoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693419.aspx) com call [`IExternalConnection::ReleaseConnection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687252(v=vs.85).aspx) **if** we register **with** `ROTFLAGS_REGISTRATIONKEEPSALIVE` .

**so conclusion:**

if we register with `ROTFLAGS_REGISTRATIONKEEPSALIVE` - [`IExternalConnection::AddConnection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686627(v=vs.85).aspx) will be called only once at registration time (really can be called say `n+1` time and `n` time - `ReleaseConnection` - but all this inside [`IRunningObjectTable::Register`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680747(v=vs.85).aspx) call.). when somebody get our object from ROT - we will be **not notified** about this. and finally [`IExternalConnection::ReleaseConnection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687252(v=vs.85).aspx) will be called also only once when we call [`IRunningObjectTable::Revoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693419.aspx).

from the other hand, if we not use `ROTFLAGS_REGISTRATIONKEEPSALIVE` flag - [`IExternalConnection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680082(v=vs.85).aspx) methods will be **not called** on `Register` and `Revoke`. but it will be **multiple time called** on [`IRunningObjectTable::GetObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683841(v=vs.85).aspx) and final `Release` (*on object proxy*). if we not implemented [`IExternalConnection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680082(v=vs.85).aspx) yourself or call [`CoDisconnectObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680756(v=vs.85).aspx) when external refs reach 0 and `fLastReleaseCloses` - we will be removed from ROT. but we free **not call** [`CoDisconnectObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680756(v=vs.85).aspx) (in this case behavior will be like we use `ROTFLAGS_REGISTRATIONKEEPSALIVE`) or say call it under some condition.

advantage - we can track every our object use in case no `ROTFLAGS_REGISTRATIONKEEPSALIVE` flag and decide by self are need disconnect when external refs reach 0 or not.

and the last - if we call  [`IRunningObjectTable::GetObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683841(v=vs.85).aspx) from same apartment where we call [`IRunningObjectTable::Register`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680747(v=vs.85).aspx) - we got not proxy, but direct object pointer. in this case of course will be no calls to [`IExternalConnection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680082(v=vs.85).aspx) methods

Comment: Now it makes sense. I've tested the scenario with an out-of-apartment client, when it disconnects, the object is released all the way to zero.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev - yes, fundamental different here between  out-of-apartment client (really proxy) and  in-apartment clients. however for the best understand situation - good be implement `IExternalConnection` on self object (only 2 simply methods) and will be very clear after this